# 熱画像から一般的な画像に変換する方法

Tags: python, 画像

熱画像から顔を認識するプログラムを作成中です。
ただカスケード型分類器、Dlibを用いた手法は一般画像用で
熱画像でも条件によっては機能するものの安定性で見ると納得いきません

https://github.com/maxbbraun/fever
これはEdgeTPU持ってないから無理

で実際に発熱を検知する機械みたいなのに顔を通したことが実生活で何回かあったのですが、どれも熱画像じゃなくて一般的なRGB画像だった気がする...
ということでもし熱画像から一般的なカメラで撮ったような画像に変換できれば
あとはカスケードで十分間に合うわけなんですが...
そんなことができる方法、何かご存じな方いらっしゃいませんか?
具体的なpythonのプログラムがあると神です

OSはwindows10です
(LinuxでしかできないというならLinuxでやりますが...)

Comment: 発熱(体温)を表示する装置は、赤外線域にも感度のあるカメラ(サーモカメラ)を使っていて、赤外線の強度で温度を測っています。熱画像からカラー画像（RGB画像）を作っている訳ではないです。

Comment: https://pc.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1233971.html　で赤外線画像をカラー化する研究が紹介されていますが、ディープラーニングによるものなのでEdgeTPUのような専用ハードウェアなしでは学習に長時間を要すると思います。

Comment: やはりEdgeTPUがないと厳しそうですね...回答ありがとうございます!